# How to join counts dependent on outer groups

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table that looks like so:

```
id | mid | oid
 1 | 400 | 1
 2 | 400 | NULL
 3 | 401 | 1
 4 | 403 | NULL
```

I am trying to return the MID, number of records with `null` OID's and number of records with `NOT null` oid's

Currently I am using this:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM drp_ledger WHERE oid IS NULL) AS que,
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM drp_ledger WHERE oid IS NOT NULL) AS finished, 
`mid` FROM drp_ledger GROUP BY `mid`
```

However this returns the ENTIRE count of `NULL` and `NOT NULL` oid's.

So I then attempted to use a `JOIN` I feel like I am close but I just cant get it to work.

```
SELECT l.`mid`, que, finished FROM drp_ledger AS l
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(id) AS que FROM drp_ledger WHERE oid IS NULL GROUP BY `mid`) AS q ON q.`mid` =  l.`mid`
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(id) AS finished FROM drp_ledger WHERE oid IS NOT NULL GROUP BY `mid`) AS f ON f.`mid` = l.`mid`
```

I would like to return:

```
mid | que | finished
400 |  1  |   1
401 |  0  |   1
403 |  1  |   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a join!

```
SELECT
  mid,
  SUM(IF(oid IS NULL,1,0)) AS oid_null,
  SUM(IF(oid IS NOT NULL,1,0)) AS oid_not_null
FROM tablename
GROUP BY mid
```

Comment: Hmm, i suppose if I get `Error Code: 1146
Table 'leechprotect.drp_ledger' doesn't exist` that would be some cpanel issue.

Comment: I have no idea about cpanel, but http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fae2/2 says, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but you forgot to select the `mid` in your subqueries.